# Fluent NHibernate - Mapping one-to-many using 2 columns

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a db schema along the lines of:

**Product**

- ID
- ProductName
- Description
- StoreBrand

**ProductVariation**

- VariationID
- ProductID
- Size
- StoreBrand
- Price

Classes, predictably, look a bit like this:

```
public class Product
{
  public virtual int ID { get; set; }
  public virtual string ProductName { get; set; }
  public virtual string Description { get; set; }
  public virtual string StoreBrand { get; set; }

  public virtual IEnumerable<ProductVariation> Variations { get; set; }
}

public class ProductVariation
{
  public virtual int VariationID { get; set; }
  public virtual int ProductID { get; set; }

  public virtual Product Product {get; set;}      

  public virtual string Size { get; set; }
  public virtual double Price { get; set; }
}
```

I've got the mapping classes like this:

```
public class ProductMapper : ClassMap<Product>
{
  public ProductMapper()
  {
    Id(x => x.ID);
    Map(x => x.ProductName);
    Map(x => x.Description);
    Map(x => x.StoreBrand);

    HasMany(x => x.Variations)
      .KeyColumn("ProductID");
  }
}

public class ProductVariationMapper : ClassMap<ProductVariation>
{
  public ProductVariation()
  {
    Id(x => x.ID);
    Map(x => x.ProductID);
    Map(x => x.Size);
    Map(x => x.Price);

    References(x => x.Product)
      .Column("ProductID");
  }
}
```

This is *kind of* working...

However, what I need to do is tie the Product.Brands together with the ProductVariation.Brands as well... (and vice versa)

So querying Product, returns a list of it's ProductVariations for that brand...
(Notice, ProductVariation doesn't have a property in the class, but it has the column for mapping)

ProductVariation.ID is non unique.
The key is ProductVariation.ID and ProductVariation.Brand (on the database)

Comment: is product.id non unique as well?

Comment: no- product.id and brand are composite

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string StoreBrand { get; set; }

    public virtual string ProductName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<ProductVariation> Variations { get; set; }

    public override Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Product)
    }

    public override Equals(Product other)
    {
        return (other != null) && (Id == other.Id) && (StoreBrand == other.StoreBrand);
    }

    public override GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return Id.GetHashCode() * 397 + StoreBrand.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}

public class ProductVariation
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product {get; set;}      

    public virtual string Size { get; set; }
    public virtual double Price { get; set; }
}

public class ProductMapper : ClassMap<Product>
{
    public ProductMapper()
    {
        // Id alone is not unique, hence compositeId
        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.ID)
            .KeyProperty(x => x.StoreBrand);

        Map(x => x.ProductName);
        Map(x => x.Description);

        HasMany(x => x.Variations)
            .KeyColumn("ProductID", "StoreBrand");
    }
}

public class ProductVariationMapper : ClassMap<ProductVariation>
{
    public ProductVariation()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID);

        Map(x => x.Size);
        Map(x => x.Price);

        References(x => x.Product)
            .Column("ProductID", "StoreBrand");
    }
}
```